# Why MySQL SELECT UNHEX(1) = :) (a smile)

Tags: mysql, sql

Why `SELECT UNHEX(1)` returns a smile?

I was expecting `1`.

What might be going on here?

Answer (score 2):

`UNHEX` tries to convert a hexadecimal number to a character string. Since you're using ASCII encoding, `UNHEX(1)` returns a smiley face. c.f. [image]

Comment: From the way-back machine, this is now referred to as [Code Page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), or also related to the venerable ANSI standard. This is what people had to use in the 1980s instead of emoji. ASCII is generally 7-bit, only up to 0x7F.

Comment: So, changing the encoding should make it return `1`? How do I do that? Or, there is an alternative to `unhex` to be used in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly states that :

> For a numeric argument N, the inverse of HEX(N) is not performed by UNHEX(). Use CONV(HEX(N),16,10) instead. See the description of HEX().

What it does is the following, still according to the documentation :

> For a string argument str, UNHEX(str) interprets each pair of
>   characters in the argument as a hexadecimal number and converts it to
>   the byte represented by the number. The return value is a binary
>   string.

So in our case, it will return the binary representation of 1 (in hexadecimal) which is simply `00000001` . And the following depends of your installation. In mine, I think that the default charset is ascii or utf8, so this "start of heading" control character, according to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) . Since it is a control character, you command line or browser may have some trouble displaying it, which may explain the smile.

If I try `SELECT UNHEX(21)`, I get `!` which is right according to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart)

After some testing, if you give numerical values to the function, il will as for a string and split two digits by two digits and translate them into a binary string.